# Search always return no result for contributors and reader, while it will work well for site collection administrate

Tags: search, 2013, permissions

I have two users group Contributor & Reader. And I have the following hierarchy:-

Site Collection   (containing both Contributor & Reader )

-Subsite A (containing both Contributor & Reader )

-Subsite B (containing both Contributor & Reader )

-Subsite C (only admin, Contribur and reader are not allowed to see this sub site)

The problem I am facing is as follow:-

1. If the admin want to search for the word “test” then all the pages will be retrieved correctly.
2. If any user inside the contributor or reader groups search for the word ”test”, then no result will be returned. although both of them can see pages containing the word “test”. And I have manually crawl all the web application content before trying the search.

So what is causing this?, and do I have to give the users read permission on Subsite C ,, for the search to work ?.

Comment: Are the files checked in and approved?

Comment: YES THEY ARE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you broken permission inheritance anywhere in the site collection?

When permission inheritance is stopped anywhere within site collection, then ASPX pages (and its content) in that site collection will not be indexed by default.

This is a security feature implemented to prevent users from using the search to view information where they don't have the correct permissions for.

To disable this behavior, go to Site Settings > Search and Offline Availability > Indexing ASPX Page Content

**Video Source**: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/tdbe12-role-based-management-in-sharepoint.aspx (Start at: 11:20 - End at: 16:07)

Comment: but at the end the reader group users are able to see pages containing the search criteria words as i mentioned abpve. so in this case they have permission to view these pages and these pages should be returned in the search. Secondly i do not think there is any index problem since the search will work well if the site collection admin is using it ..

Comment: Hi John, did disabling the behavior solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

Check under WebApplication permission that your crawl account has Read Access.

In Central Admin:

> Application Management --> Manage web applications --> Click the line
>   of the web app --> In Ribbon "User Policy"

Make sure that the Search Crawling account is added as Full Read

Comment: yes the sps_farm username has a full read permission

Comment: And sps_farm is your "Default content access account"?

Comment: i am not sure,,, how i can check this please ...

Comment: Go to Manage Service Applications --> Search Service Application. In the middle "System Status" you will se "Default Content access account"

Comment: yes it is also SPS_Farm

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me recently. Depending on the total items in the list or document library, you will have to WAIT for some hours. In my case, i have 62942 document in my document library, my user had to wait for like 12 hours for the page to properly re-index for the user. This usually happen when you just add the user to the list or document library. I hope this helps?