# End user search result is zero but as a farm admin i get full result

Tags: search

I have a purchasing site and members in the contributor groups aren't able to get result back. but when i do the same search i get result. I am clue less where to begin. They all have contribute permission to the site and the libraries. zero records return.

Comment: followed this and ran an incremental crawl. and now user can see the search result. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69049/search-always-return-no-result-for-contributors-and-reader-while-it-will-work-w?rq=1